# gnuplot replace old plot with new

Tags: gnuplot

I am running a program which uses a plotting library for gnuplot. I am running a script and  am supposed to view the resultant plot in real time.

Inside the do loop, the plotting command would come up say 100 times. Because of this I am obtaining 100 seperate gnuplot windows containing the plot.

The program is like

```
do i=1,100
...
...
call plota1(x,y)
end do
```

Is there any way such that I do not get such 100 plots, and say, when the (i+1)th plot comes, it will come in the same gnuplot window replacing the ith plot?

The plotting subroutine used is as follows.

```
subroutine plota1(x,y)
real*8::x(:),y(:)
integer l,u,i
l=lbound(x(:),dim=1)
u=ubound(x(:),dim=1)
open(1,file="p.dat")
open(2,file="p.plt")

do i=l,u
write(1,*) x(i),y(i)
end do


write(2,*) "p 'p.dat' u 1:2 w l"

call execute_command_line('gnuplot -p p.plt')
close(1,status='delete')
close(2,status='delete')
end subroutine plota1
```

The plotting command comes from the line "write(2,*) "p 'p.dat' u 1:2 w l"".
What should I add there to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the plotting command, but with the fact that for each call to `plot1a` you start a new `gnuplot` process, `call execute_command_line('gnuplot -p p.plt')`.

In order to replot in the same window (erasing previous plot with `plot` command, or its abbreviation `p`, or plotting on top of previous curves with `replot`), you have to have a single `gnuplot` process. This is possible if your scripting language allows piping.

Alternatively, you have to keep expanding the `p.dat` and `p.plt` file with the new data and plotting commands, e.g using the multi-data-set capability of `gnuplot`.